# What formula can fit these data?

Tags: statistics

I would like to know what kind of formula can best fit these data, as shown in the following:

[image]

such that I can compute $y$ given only $x$.

**Update**:

Data are placed in [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12JDRctQwlWz0x_btTxFl-KhCrqRNO1Hj).

Comment: If you can post the data, I can do a statistical fit.  It is probably something of the form $a + x^b e^{-c x}$.

Comment: @david Thanks! I posted my data in [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12JDRctQwlWz0x_btTxFl-KhCrqRNO1Hj).

Comment: A quick search shows a reasonable fit by:  $f(x)= 0.03 + .4 e^{-x/20} + {\rm Poisson}[4;x]$... but you can play around with parameters using statistical fitting software.